# Display links in a list item in the center of the div

Tags: html, css

I have made an ul and some li inside and then some links. I want to center the links into the div but i can't. I have tried text-align:center; but it is not working.  Here is the code:

CSS:

```
ul.simple-pagination {
    list-style: none;
}
.simple-pagination {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.simple-pagination ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.simple-pagination li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.light-theme a, .light-theme span {
    float: left;
    color: #666;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    min-width: 14px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #efefef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #efefef 100%); /* IF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#efefef)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* W3C */
}
.light-theme a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #FCFCFC;
    color:grey;
}
.light-theme .current {
    background: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    border-color: #444;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
    cursor: default;
}
.light-theme .ellipse {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
}            
#pagination_container {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px groove #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pagination_container">
     <ul class="simple-pagination">
          <li class='light-theme'> <a class='current' href="?page=1">1</a></i> 
          <li class='light-theme'><a href="?page=2">2</a></li> 
          <li class='light-theme'><a href="?page=3">3</a></li> 
          <li class='light-theme'><a href='blog.php?page=2'>Next</a> </li>    
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: looks as exactly as u wanted not? https://jsfiddle.net/c7u3rhb0/

Comment: Sorry i want to display the li in the center of the div. Thats mean no matter if the div is 300px or 1000px they should be in the center of the div. And now they are on the left side as you can see

Comment: okey then i cant help u I'm not an html,css  pro^^ even it should be very easy to solve :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `text-align: center` to the `li` s like this:

```css
   #pagination_container{ text-align: center }
   .simple-pagination{ display: inline-block; list-style: none }
   .simple-pagination li{ display: inline-block; text-align: center }
.light-theme a, .light-theme span {
   float: left;
color: #666;
font-size:14px;
line-height:24px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #BBB;
min-width: 14px;
padding: 0 7px;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
background: #efefef; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #efefef 100%); /* IF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#efefef)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<div id="pagination_container">
     <ul class="simple-pagination">
          <li class='light-theme'><a class='current' href="?page=1">1</a></i><li class='light-theme'><a href="?page=2">2</a></li><li class='light-theme'><a href="?page=3">3</a></li><li class='light-theme'><a href='blog.php?page=2'>Next</a></li>    
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: it is working! check the obove snippet. I made some editions

Comment: but why is the margin between number 1 and 2 less than the others?

Comment: I made little change to markup to cover that. keep in mind that `display:inline-block` needs colsing `</li>` s to be followed by the next opening `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `text-align: center;` to the `<ul>`. Does this work for you?

```css
.simple-pagination {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.simple-pagination ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.simple-pagination li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}      

.light-theme a, .light-theme span {
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  min-width: 14px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #efefef; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #efefef 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#efefef)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#efefef 100%); /* W3C */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.light-theme a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #FCFCFC;
  color:grey;
}

.light-theme .current {
  background: #666;
  color: #FFF;
  border-color: #444;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
  cursor: default;
}

.light-theme .ellipse {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}            

#pagination_container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px groove #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="simple-pagination">
    <li class='light-theme'> <a class='current' href="?page=1">1</a></li> 
    <li class='light-theme'><a href="?page=2">2</a></li> 
    <li class='light-theme'><a href="?page=3">3</a></li> 
    <li class='light-theme'><a href='blog.php?page=2'>Next</a> </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```